# Oracle SQL in clause - slow in speed

Tags: sql, oracle

Query 1 below is really slow in speed.

```
select * from my_table
where col1 in (
    ... multiple complicated joins ...
);
```

Suppose the (multiple complicated joins) returns 1,2,...,50 and it runs fast.

```
  ... multiple complicated joins ...
```

By replacing the join by its output, Query2 below also runs much faster.

```
select * from my_table
where col1 in (
    1,2,...,50
);
```

Is there a way to insert the output of the (multiple complicated joins) into a list-like variable?

```
select * from my_table
where col1 in &col1_list;
```

my_table: 2G table and col1 is not indexed

multiple complicated joins: returns around 50 values within 1 seconds

Query 1: running time = 5 mins

Query 2: running time = 2 seconds

Note: I only have read permission to the database, so i cannot create any temporary tables.

Comment: using the IN clause and feeding it values from a SELECT is the 'right way to go' generally. if it's slow, it's probably bc your multiple, complicated joins query is slow. You could tune that query...or if it's as good as it gets, you can ask the db owner to help out with something like a materialized view

Comment: That's what confused me because the (multiple complicated joins) runs very fast.

Comment: ok, well how many values does it return? it might return 1,000 values, very quickly, but then that turns into 1,000 values for the first query to filter...and is col1 indexed?

Comment: it returns around 50 values and col1 is not indexed.

Comment: Can you please post an EXPLAIN? There are lots of hypotheticals in this....

Comment: I Edited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about to join your complex joins.

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE mt JOIN (... multiple complicated joins ...)temp on temp.col = mt.col1
```

Comment: Thank you! The join works much better than in. Do you know why this is the case?

Comment: In your example you are loading all values for IN clause then  comparing with another value, but in case of join it will load only matching values.